# Cat Vocal Exercises for a cat with a quiet voice?

Tags: cats, vocalizations

Ok, I know this one is sort of weird but here it is: Is there any sort of vocal exercises for my cat?

Backstory: I had a few cat's and I enjoyed hearing them purr, mew and etc. The problem is that my current cat sounds... weak?!?

When me and my wife adopted him, he was about 2 months old, with pink eye and a flu. We nursed him back to health and he looks pretty healthy now (he has 6 months already) but in comparison with the previous cats I had, his mews seem miserable. My worry is that he got his lungs underdeveloped due to sickness when he was a little kitten (he is like 2 kg now).

So far I make him 'beg' every time I prepare wet food for him, and award him with a full bowl every time he starts mewing loud enough. But it doesn't seem enough.

My question is:

### Is there anything else I can do and should I be worried about his weak voice?

Comment: According to my television, all it takes is some meow mix and they'll start singing until you give it to them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Concern about lung development**

If you are concerned about your cat's health, you should take your cat to the veternarian. The vet will listen to your cat's breathing and may take pictures (x-rays or other types of scans) to determine if your cat's lungs are healthy and functioning well. This type of investigative work we cannot do over the internet and must be done by your vet.

**Vocal volume**

I have mostly cats of Siamese descent (visually noticable by the pointed coat and blue eyes, but the relevant characteristic here is that they Talk All Of The Time). We have one cat who is not Siamese.

As a kitten, he made cute little *chirrup* sounds when jumping onto and off of things, but no meows.  Later, as our Siamese population grew (and he aged), the *chirrups* disappeared and he started meowing like everyone else.

Usually they are the somewhat misleadingly named "silent meow". The cat looks like he is meowing, but we can't hear anything. The meow sound is too high for us to hear (the cat hears it fine). When we can hear him meow, they are more softer, higher pitched, and threadier sounding than the Siamese.

What I suspect is happening with my cat (and perhaps with your cat) is that some/all of the meow sound is in the range where we can't hear it. Your cat's meow volume may be perfectly fine, you just can't hear all of the sound!

If this is the case, there isn't any way to train your cat to meow "lower". It's just the type of voice he has.

Comment: I already took it to a vet. The vet said he is fine and that I should be happy the cat doesn't have annoying mew. But still I worry for him.

Thanks for the info on cat mews! Can't wait for his mew to normalize ^^.

Comment: As long as his lungs are healthy, you're fine. My 20 year old cat has deformed vocal cords that the vet told us are why she seems to have no voice: when she's extremely stressed she will occasionally voice her meows, but mostly they sound like feline heavy breathing.